# Upload File in S3 of AWS

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am uploading file in s3 writing the below code:

```
String filePath=KeyProvider.localFolerPath + KeyProvider.suffix +KeyProvider.FileNameToUpload; 

// upload file to folder and set it to public
String fileName = folderName + KeyProvider.suffix +KeyProvider.remoteFileName ;
s3client.putObject(
            new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, new File(filePath))
                    .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicReadWrite));`
```

It is throwing error  like

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied

Please suggest me where is the error i have provided bucket name key and secret in a seperate constant file.

Thanks..

Comment: @stdunbar. Thanks for correcting the format and editing the question.

Answer (score 3):

did you check Amazon's documents ?

And, be careful. You need to set access_key & access_secret strings to s3 client.

- [Performing Operations on Amazon S3 Objects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html)

example

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;

// "credentialsProvider" will be created by some classes for example "AWSStaticCredentialsProvider"
//
// BasicAWSCredentials cred = new BasicAWSCredentials("xxxxx", "yyyyy");
// AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(cred);
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(credentialsProvider).build();

try {
    s3.putObject(bucket_name, key_name, file_path);
} catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
    System.exit(1);
}
```

**EDIT**

S3 policy can handle deny/allow access according to credentials or IP addresses. Do you configure such policy ?

Comment: Thanks for your help however  the code that I have shared is same as you suggested.

Comment: @prabhat kumar Then, do you use correct accesskey ? If your access key's owner doesn't have right permission, it will not work.

Comment: Thanks for your effort in correcting me but access key and secret all are right.I can see my application can handshake with s3, list the bucket there.However when trying to upload the file then I am getting access denied response.

Comment: @prabhatkumar OK. Would you please describe your using "bucket_name", "key_name" and "file_path" to pass the function "#putObject" ? And I would like to know user information about the key owner. Key owner should have S3 access controll or just admincontroll.